# SAQL- Wave analytics Convert to number

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql

Is anyone knows how to convert date or string to a number in SAQL?

specifically convert this: toString(now(), "yyyy") into number

Comment: I do not think there is a option to convert String to a number, but you could convert date to number using function like daysBetween(date1, date2). can you redefine your question to specific scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to query you should be able to:

```
["current year + 1 year"]
```

Would be able to provide a better answer if you specified what you were trying to do with this value and how you are attempting to calculate it

> Add and Subtract Dates You can add and subtract dates using the
>   relative date keywords

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_saql.meta/bi_dev_guide_saql/bi_saql_functions_date.htm?search_text=current%20year

Comment: I want to use current year in a formula but I don't know How to do it. This function toString(now(), "yyyy") gives 2017 but cannot be used because the type is a date and I can't multiply by a number. I cannot simply put 2017 because is static.

Comment: @MariaJoão - i have no idea what you are trying to do. Your tag is SAQL so if you want to use current year I have provided you an option. otherwise you are going to have to be specific. Like where are you wanting to use it, what are you adding to it, how do you calculate the additive value, etc. More Detail

Comment: I explained with more detail here :) https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171037/saql-using-current-year-and-doing-calculations-with-dates-in-a-formula-condition