# SAQL Using Current year and doing calculations with dates in a Formula Condition

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql

I want to do calculations with dates and use 'current year' in a formula condition. When I tried to manipulate dates in a formula I always receive an error of incompatibles types; NUMBER AND DATE.

Because of that I had to convert the date fields into numbers in the dataflow. It worked but I didn't resolve the issue of current year because it is impossible to convert a field that change with time. The condition and the formula is the following:

```
case
    when  'Date_Month'+'Date_Year'*12> 2+'current year'*12 then 0 when ('current-'Date_Year')*12+(2-'Date_Month')) % max('Billing_Periodicity') == 0 then 'Parcel_Bill' else 0
```

Many Thanks for your attention and help

Answer (score 0):

Hi there what I understand by your question is you want to change the date relative to today's date.
this can be done by using function 
    `date_to_epoch()`
of saql you convert current date to epoch seconds and add seconds to it according to yo your need 
Example below shows how I changed current year to next year

```
q = foreach q generate date_to_string(toDate(date_to_epoch(year_last_day(toDate(date_to_epoch(now()))))+86400),"yyyy")  as nextyear,date_to_string(toDate(date_to_epoch(year_last_day(toDate(date_to_epoch(now()))))),"yyyy")  as currentyear;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the ['Date Functions'](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_saql.meta/bi_dev_guide_saql/bi_saql_functions_date.htm) in Analytics SQL Reference?